# Possible to send specific elasticsearch queries to a reserved set of replicas?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a weekly process which runs a huge number of elasticsearch queries over the course of a few hours. This affects the performance of our elasticsearch cluster for other applications.

We're considering spinning up a completely separate cluster just for this task, so that it doesn't have a negative affect on our other usage.

Since we're running a cluster, we already have our shards replicated to multiple nodes. This made me think: wouldn't it be neat if we could tell our expensive operation to ONLY query a subset of those replica nodes, and tell the rest of our code to stay clear of those replicas?

If we could do this, we wouldn't need to spin up a separate cluster at all. We could essentially reserve a subset of the replicas for the weekly task and have our other applications query the remaining replicas.

That way, if the weekly task caused performance issues on the nodes assigned to it the rest of our applications wouldn't notice.

Is this possible to do with Elasticsearch? Alternatively, is there another path we should be looking at here?

Answer (score 0):

I asked Honza at Elastic about this and he pointed me to the preference argument that can be passed with a search:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-preference.html

This is exactly what I needed: for an individual search query it allows me to specify exactly which nodes (or shards, or primary-only, or replica-only) I want to use to run that query.

I can also connect directly to a specific node and request a preference of "_local" to cause the query to be executed directly on that node.

I think this means I can configure my intensive task to connect directly to a subset of the cluster nodes (after disabling sniffing so it doesn't detect and connect to the others) and use the _local preference to cause the elasticsearch Python client library to load balance queries between nodes in that subset.